# How to define a default NULL value to Hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive

Suppose one table contains 3 columns and I render a query like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, null as col4 from table;
```

In this case null values are not properlly getting reflected. I got error in UNION operations stated "Runtime NULL exception". Please help on this

Answer (score 0):

What distribution/version  of Hadoop you are using this . I tried this on IDH and it just worked fine. Can you also paste complete error message

hive (default)> describe table4;

OK

fld1    string

fld2    string

hive (default)> select fld1, fld2, null as fld3 from table4;

A   1   NULL

B   1   NULL

C   1   NULL

Adding below as per questioner's comment,

I tried this cast , it describe now as string. you can cast as per your need

create table table6 as select fld1, fld2, cast(null as string) fld3 from table4;

hive (default)> describe table6;
OK

fld1 string
fld2 string
fld3 string

Comment: ok.. Please create a table on top of it like this. 
Create table table5 as select fld1, fld2, null as fld3 from table4; and describe the table5. here the default type is taken as VOID that is creating the problem while joining.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on some sample tables and it worked for me without any errors. Example query:

```
select * from
(select col1, NULL as col2 from table1 LIMIT 10

UNION ALL

select col1, col2 from table2LIMIT 10) q1
```